# many-to-many relationship with TClientDataSet

Tags: database, delphi, many-to-many, tclientdataset

I have two database tables:

1. students table
2. classes table

There is a many-to-many relationship between the two tables: a student can go to several classes and a class can have several students.

I would like to implement the tables in Delphi with TClientDatasets and have a TDBGrid which list all the students and a second TDBGrid which list all the classes which the currently selected student attends.

As far as I understand it I need a join table which establishes the relationship between the students and the classes table with the following fields:

- StudentID
- ClassID

But I don't know how to implement the relationships between the different TClientDatasets so that I get the TDBGrids working as described above.

Comment: In this case the fact that a class can contain several students is irrelevant. Build your index by student, then class within student.

Comment: I think what you want is a master-detail relationship. Try to search for these keywords.